# How can I hide a Div element if an inner <p> element is blank?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a community visualisation in Google Data Studio (Templated Record) which allows me to use HTML and CSS to display records. I'm fairly new to all this and I'm having some trouble with what I want to achieve so hoping someone can help.

What I'm trying to do is be able to hide a Div element if it's inner

element is blank. All of the

elements I'm using are variables so I have no way of knowing if they'll be blank record from  record.

Here's an example of of the HTML:

```
<div class="aDiv">
<h3>Study Summary:</h3><p> {{Summary}} </p></div><br>
```

Where  is a fixed Header and

is the variable being pulled from a Google Sheet.

Here's the CSS:

```
.aDiv {border: 1px outset #193e72; padding: 0em 1em 2em;}
h3 {color: #193e72; font-size: 1.7em; margin: 0;  padding-top: 0.5em;}
p {font-size: 1.3em}
```

Here's how it currently looks:

[screenshot of Div element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xgfZ.png)

So basically I'd like to hide this entire element if the

variable is blank.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please add more information for example your attemps to solve your problem

Comment: With CSS you cannot identify parent elements so working from the inner empty element up the DOM to the container that you wish to hide cannot be done with CSS alone. With Javascript this is a relatively easy thing to do however.